# Highlight names in sheet1 that are in sheet2

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use findnext and dictionary to compare the lists in the two sheets and highlight the cell in sheet 1 (sheet name is shH) (text in Column A) if it appears in sheet2 (sheet name is shS) (text in Column B).

It is showing

> Compile Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

for `FINDNEXT`

and shows

> Runtime error "9": Subscript out of range

for the line `x=ar(i,1)`.

```vb
For i = 0 To dict.Count - 1
    x = ar(i, 1)
    Set rg = shH.range("A2", shH.range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set cell = rg.Find("*x*", MatchCase:=False)
    
    If Not cell Is Nothing Then
        cell.Interior.colourindex = 27
        first = cell.Address
        Do
            Set cell = rg.FindNext("*cell*", Matchcare:=False)
            cell.Interior.colourindex = 27
        Loop While first <> cell.adress
    End If
    
Next i
```

My logic is use dictionary to record the names shown in sheet2(shS) and find them in sheet1(shH) and highlight them, highlight all that match partially.

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of the module. This will force you to declare all variables and indicate the various typos that you have in the code. If then still something doesn't work, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65660109/edit) your post adding the complete code and reporting the issue(s) more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly what you want. This code will compare every cell in the data set to the other sheet. If they are equal it will fill the cell with color.

It will work only if both data sets are in the same range.

When you try it, don't forget to change the values in the config section of the code.

```
Sub highlight()

Dim this_row, db_col, last_row, start_row As Integer
Dim name_s1, name_s2 As String

'CONFIG THIS BEFORE YOU RUN THE MACRO
'-----------------------------------------
db_col = 2                'in what column number is the data?
start_row = 2             'in what column does the data start?
name_s1 = "Sheet1"        'name of first sheet
name_s2 = "Sheet2"        'name of second sheet
'------------------------------------------

'get the last row of the data set
last_row = Sheets(name_s1).Cells(Rows.Count, db_col).End(xlUp).Row

'loop through the column
For this_row = start_row To last_row

        'compare cells from sheet1 to sheet2
        If Sheets(name_s1).Cells(this_row, db_col) = _
        Sheets(name_s2).Cells(this_row, db_col) Then

        'highlight the cells that have the same value
        Application.Sheets(name_s1).Range("B" & this_row).Select
        Selection.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
        Selection.Interior.TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314

        End If

Next this_row

End Sub
```